# Find statements related to a Connection

Tags: java, connection

I am developing on a big application which uses a Connection Pool and has lots of classes using its connections.
Recently we had some issues because some classes were not closing the statements before invoking the connection.close() method, wrongly believing that when the connection is closed any related statement is also closed.

At the moment I am refactoring some code and developing an abstract class which will manage the connections (get them from and put them back into datasource) and leave the statement details to be implemented into subclasses.

In order to avoid future errors related to statements not being closed, I thought about implementing some check before returing the conneciton into the Pool and if I find some opened statements either close them or log a Warning.

The resulting class would look like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseLoader {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public final DatabaseValues load(DatabaseParams params) {

    DatabaseValues result = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        result = load(connection, params);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // some logging;
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                if (validateStatements(connection)){
                    logger.warn("The Connection is being returned into the POOL with opened Statments!");
                }
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // some logging.
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

    }

    protected abstract DatabaseValues load(Connection connection, DatabaseParams params);

    private boolean validateStatements(Connection connection){
        // Do Something here to validate if statements were properly closed.
    }

}
```

However, I found no way to recover the statements from the connection interface.

So:

1. Is this even possible without having to depend on specific implementations?
2. Would you recommend this approach?

Many thanks,

Carles

Comment: I have done exactly this in the past, but it required creating a 'proxy' JDBC Connection object that tracked each statement created, and would close them when the connection was 'returned'. This was 'last century', so things may have changed, and, if I recall, I used a java.lanf.reflect.Proxy

Answer (score 1):

`Connection.close` API says

```
Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released.
```

if it is even a Connection Pool where the connection is not actually closed, it is the Connection Pool provider duty to close all Statements and ResultSets created by this Connection, and this is what good providers do in practice, see commons-dbcp http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingConnection.html#close() it says `Closes the underlying connection, and close any Statements that were not explicitly closed.`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this is not applicable in my case, where I am using OracleDataSource implementation.
Actually, looking at Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/basic.htm#i1006632) it clearly says:
`You must explicitly close the ResultSet and Statement objects after you finish using them...If you do not explicitly close your ResultSet and Statement objects, serious memory leaks could occur`